# Why don't I have any comments in my py-files? (Django)

Tags: python, django, comments

I'm following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/) about creating a simple blog with Django. I see that this guy has a lot of comments in his py-files with explanations and such. My py-files don't look at all the same. For example, in settings.py I don't have any varibale called TEMPLATE_DIRS, but in this guys file it looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Since I'm a newbie I would of course appreciate the help that these comments and pre-defined variables provide. Why don't I have them? Have Django removed them in a later version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Old django version (< 1.4) has `TEMPLATE_DIRS` when creating new project . new version, don't .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the answer is [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12493)

Its because of your django version that you are using. in [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/) tutorial they used django 1.3. its 
existing in the django 1.3. But Its misssing in djang 1.4 and later versions.

So add the below code in your settings.py

```
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Comment: Oh okay, too bad they removed it because it would have been a good help for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the author of the tutorial wrote his own comments so that readers would better understand each of the settings. It may also be that in a newer version of Django the core developers thought it would be simpler to leave them out of the default settings file created.

It doesn't matter much because each setting such as `TEMPLATE_DIRS` has a [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs). So you can check django documentation for their meaning.

Comment: Sure, of course. But what I would have appreciated was the comments in the .py-files. They would have made it easier for someone like me with very little knowledge about Django. But I guess they removed it for a reason.